# How can I dynamically calculate row height by row index for VariableSizeList?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-window

I need to render long list via react-window library. I can't be sure that all rows will be the same size so it forces me to use VariableSizeList. So is there a way to calculate row height when you know only index of row and actual data to be rendered?

I think it's possible to render it somehow not visible to the end user and get height from but I'm not sure is it the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes when using `VariableSizeList` specify an `itemSize` function.

eg

```
itemSize = {(i) => onGetItemSize(rows[i])}
```

The onGetItemSize measures the content by:

1. returning a single line height, if content is small.
2. writing the content to a empty element, with the same width and properties as your row. Then measuring the element height, before emptying the element again.

For example:

```
 onGetItemSize={((row) =>
                {
                let text = row.original.text;
                // if no text, or text is short, don't bother measuring.
                if (!text || text.length < 15)
                    return rowHeight;

                // attempt to measure height by writting text to a, kind of hidden element.
                let hiddenElement = document.getElementById(this.hiddenFieldName());
                if (hiddenElement)
                {
                    hiddenElement.textContent = text;
                    let ret = hiddenElement.offsetHeight;
                    hiddenElement.textContent = '';

                    if (ret > 0)
                        return Math.max(ret, rowHeight);
                }

                // fallback
                return rowHeight;
            })}
```

Then include this empty element at an appropriate place in the DOM.

```
<div id={this.hiddenFieldName()} style={{ visibility: 'visible', whiteSpace: 'normal' }} />
```